# WP recurring downtime, errors | (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01075:

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx

Each couple of days the WP applications are not available for a few minuts.
In the server log I see 503s logged together with these type of errors:

```
2020-12-09 11:46:11 Error   141.101.76.7        (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01075: Error dispatching request to :, referer: https://www.domainname.nl/              Apache error
2020-12-09 11:46:11 Error   141.101.76.7        4342#0: *280039 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream              nginx error
2020-12-09 11:46:18 Error   108.162.229.157     (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01075: Error dispatching request to :               Apache error
2020-12-09 11:46:18 Error   162.158.158.254     (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01075: Error dispatching request to :               Apache error
2020-12-09 11:46:18 Error   108.162.229.157     4342#0: *280041 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream              nginx error
2020-12-09 11:46:18 Error   162.158.158.254     4342#0: *280043 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream              nginx error
2020-12-09 11:46:30 Error   141.101.99.150      (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01075: Error dispatching request to :               Apache error
2020-12-09 11:46:30 Error   141.101.99.150      4342#0: *280045 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream              nginx error
2020-12-09 11:46:34 Error   172.69.170.125      (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01075: Error dispatching request to :, referer: https://www.https://www.domainname.nl               Apache error
2020-12-09 11:46:34 Error   172.69.170.125      4342#0: *279982 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream              nginx error
2020-12-09 11:46:42 Error   172.69.170.125  503 GET /shop/nl/ HTTP/1.0  https://www.domainname.nl/shop/nl/  Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)  1.38 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2020-12-09 11:46:42 Error   172.69.170.15       (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01075: Error dispatching request to :, referer: https://www.domainname.nl/shop/nl/              Apache error
2020-12-09 11:46:42 Error   172.69.170.15       4342#0: *280048 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream              nginx error
```

I would sincerely like some help or advise on this please

Comment: Seems like the service you approach is unavailable. Did you check why?

Comment: No, I just keep getting this errors